# The colors of nodes in Force-Directed layout using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am getting a problem with coloring the nodes in Force-Directed Graph in D3.js. The graph is taken from:

> http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I am having the JavaScript code in JSP file. The graph is displayed properly. The problem is the `group` attribute does not seem to work correctly in the JSON file. I need to color some nodes with `Blue ("group":1)` and the other nodes with `Red ("group":6)`. The integer numbers for colors groups are stored in Java Managed beans. I serialize the arraylist and send it to JavaScript as `JSON`. Here are my codes in the JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%> 
<%@ page import= "ch.master.Connection.*"%>
<%@ page import= "java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org       /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<style>

.node {
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
 stroke: #999;
 stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js charset=UTF-8"></script>
<script>

var Name = ${connection.list};
var Source = ${connection.source};
var Target = ${connection.target};
var Colors = ${connection.colour};
var linksArray = new Array();
var namesArray  = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{ 
namesArray.push({"name" : Name[i], "group" : parseInt(Colors[i])});
}

for (var j=0; j<Target.length; j++)
{
linksArray.push({"source" : parseInt(Source[j]), "target" : parseInt(Target[j])});
}

init();

function init()
{
var width = 1500,
height = 900;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);
force
.nodes(array)
.links(linksArray)
.start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(linksArray)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(namesArray)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
}

</script>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

the output is: some nodes are colored with `Blue ("group": 1)` which is correct but unfortunately the nodes with `"group":6` are not red. They are light Blue. What is the problem in this case. I need to show the other nodes with Red. I already added the `"group: 6"` that represents the `Red` color for these nodes. Could anyone please assist me to solve this problem. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're using a d3 default colour scale (`var color = d3.scale.category20()`), so you're getting the default colours.  If you have a specific mapping of colours for group values that you want to use, you need to create your own [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) and set its domain and range.

Comment: Thank you for your response. According to the example I have taken the code from, it seems that (var color = d3.scale.category20()) works properly. However, I will try to work on ordinal scale and see what the difference is.

Comment: The category20 colour scale [is an ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-categorical-colors) that has been initializad with specific colours as the output range.  When you use the scale, the values you pass in are added to the input domain in the order you use them.  That works fine if you're okay with default colours, but not if you want particular colours for particular groups.  When you get it working, come back and post your code as an answer (and mark it accepted).

Comment: I will work on it now and post it as an answer if I get the right results. Thank you for your help.